# как вернуть string escaping в swift 3?

Tags: алгоритм, ios, swift, swift3

Здравствуйте! 
Пытаюсь парсить текст по api в вк, но с возвратом текста есть небольшие неполадки, в интернете почитал что нужно использовать что-то там асинхронно и объясняют языком не совсем понятным мне для реализации)) Может кто подсказать как вернуть text?

```
func getJSON(rs: String, tx: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

            guard self != nil else { return }

            let baseURL = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getById?posts=-34451036_490279)&access_token=f169c8734a2d55e1758dd&v=5.64"

            let url = URL(string: baseURL)
            let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

            session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
                    let response = swiftyJSON[rs].arrayValue

                    for tobject in response {

                        completion(tobject[tx].stringValue)
                        print(completion)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    getJSON(rs: "response", tx: "text") { result in
        print("RESULT \(result)")
    }

}
```

Уже перепробовал все что можно, ничего не получается, на всех форумах тишина, подскажите как нужно правильно написать? Мне нужен текст, который находится тут

> completion(tobject[tx].stringValue)

Если реализовывать так:

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            let response = swiftyJSON[rs].arrayValue

            for tobject in response {

                let text = tobject[tx].stringValue
                print(text)
            }

        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

То текст спокойно выводится. Которые сутки всю ночь сижу и не могу реализовать этот кусок кода. 
Изначально функция выглядела так:

```
func getJSON(rs: String, tx: String) -> String {

    var text = ""

    let inputURL = self.inputURL.text

    let link = inputURL?.components(separatedBy: "wall")

    let baseURL = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getById?posts=\(link![1])&access_token=87c166c4014fa57d4eae&v=5.64"

    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            let response = swiftyJSON[rs].arrayValue

            for tobject in response {

                let text = tobject[tx].stringValue
            }

        }
    }
    task.resume()

    return text
}
```

Но ничего из этого не работает, понимают что ответ близок, но... Очень прошу помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так попробовать

```
func getJSON(rs: String, tx: String, completion:(String) -> Void)){

var text = ""

let inputURL = self.inputURL.text

let link = inputURL?.components(separatedBy: "wall")
let baseURL = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getById?posts=\(link![1])&access_token=87c166c4014fa57d4eae&v=5.64"
let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)

let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error == nil {

        let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
        let response = swiftyJSON[rs].arrayValue

        for tobject in response {

            let text = tobject[tx].stringValue
        }
        completion(text)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

}

тогда вызов будет такой

```
getJSON(rs: param1, tx: param2) { (resultString) in 
// тут делаем все что нужно со строкой
}
```

Или еще такой вариант

func getJSON(rs: String, tx: String) -> String {

```
var text = ""

let inputURL = self.inputURL.text

let link = inputURL?.components(separatedBy: "wall")

let baseURL = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.getById?posts=\(link![1])&access_token=87c166c4014fa57d4eae&v=5.64"

let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
let request = NSURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

let que = DispatchQueue.init(label: "que1")
que.sync {

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

           let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
           let response = swiftyJSON[rs].arrayValue

           for tobject in response {

               let text = tobject[tx].stringValue
           }

        }
   }
   task.resume()

}

return text
```

}

Comment: или нужно что бы метод именно возвращал строку ?